# Count specific elements in a div container on the top level only

Tags: javascript

My HTML Structure is like this:

```
<div container>
    <div child_container>
        <span 1> 1 </span>
        <span 2> 2 </span>
    </div child_container>>
    <span 3> 3 </span> 
    <span 4> 4 </span>
</div container>
```

I want to count the **span 3** and **span 4** inside my container. Not the spans inside the **child_container**.

I have tried several things:

This will count everything inside **container**:

```
var countElementsAfter = columnNamesOverview_comparison_values.getElementsByTagName("span").length;
```

This wont work:

```
var countElementsAfter = columnNamesOverview_comparison_values.getElementsByTagName("span").childNodes[0]length;
```

And this, result is still 1, although I have two elements:

```
var countElementsAfter1 = columnNamesOverview_comparison_values.getElementsByTagName("span");
var k = [];
for (var i=0, len=c.length; i<len; ++i) {
    k[k.length] = c[i];
    }
```

How can I count the **span** elements in my **container** without counting the child elements?

Comment: check css selector https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) which can use css selector

```js
const spans = document.querySelectorAll("#container > span")
console.log(spans.length)
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="child_container">
        <span 1> 1 </span>
        <span 2> 2 </span>
    </div>
    <span 3> 3 </span> 
    <span 4> 4 </span>
</div>
```

in case you can't have a selector for the parent element (and thus, can't select it's child specifically), you can loop over it's children and filter

```js
const container = document.querySelector("#container")
const spans = Array.from(container.children)
  .filter(child => child.tagName === "SPAN")
console.log(spans.length)
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="child_container">
        <span 1> 1 </span>
        <span 2> 2 </span>
    </div>
    <span 3> 3 </span> 
    <span 4> 4 </span>
</div>
```